# How to create animation in cocos2d 3.0?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So I tried

```
self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
```

But then I discovered that CCRepeatForever has been renamed and CCAnimate removed. How can I replace this?

All code: http://pastebin.com/VnrtiCwb

Comment: CCActionRepeatForever, CCActionAnimate .. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/

Comment: You can also use CCAnimatedSprite which makes this very simple: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/331/ccanimatedsprite-the-easiest-way-to-animate-a-spr

Answer (score 1):

`CCRepeatForever` was replaced with `CCActionRepeatForever` and `CCAnimate` with `CCActionAnimate`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"sv_anim_1.png"]; // comes from your .plist file
sprite.position = ccp( [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize].width/2, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize].height/2 );

CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlas.png"];
[batchNode addChild:sprite];
[self addChild:batchNode];

NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
 {
      //NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"an1_anim%d.png",i];
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"an1_anim%d.png",i]];
        [animFrames addObject:frame];
 }

 animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:0.2f];
 [sprite runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
```