# cocos2d v3 Sprite animation issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Sprite animation issues.

Using this example which seems to work for others:
[How to create animation in cocos2d 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598354/how-to-create-animation-in-cocos2d-3-0)

So I do this:

```
NSMutableArray *ballAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 1; i <= 11; ++i)
{
[ballAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]     
  spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"discoball1200x2008c16-%d.png", i]]];
}

CCAnimation *ballAnim = [CCAnimation
                         animationWithSpriteFrames:ballAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

discoBallSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"discoball1200x2008c16-1.png"];

discoBallSprite.position  = ccp(upper1Body.position.x,upper1Body.position.y-200);

CCActionAnimate *animationAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:ballAnim];
CCActionRepeatForever *repeatingAnimation = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:animationAction];
discoBallSprite.scaleX = 0.25;
discoBallSprite.scaleY = 0.25;

[discoBallSprite runAction:repeatingAnimation];

[self addChild:discoBallSprite z:10];
```

I get the following error:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Obviously the error message is saying my image file is nil but it seems perfectly fine.

I tried renaming files to remove the extra "-" character but no change (I also renamed files outside of Xcode and re-imported with new name).

All my images are in Resources folder.

I tried moving images out of Resources folder to next level up but still the error.

The naming of them seems fine.

Any ideas what else to check?

Comment: I just added an NSLog right before it populates array: `NSLog(@"discoball1200x2008c16-%d.png:",1);` and the debug spits out "discoball1200x2008c16-1.png" which is perfectly the filename of my first image.

Comment: Did this: `[ballAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"discoball1200x2008c16-%d.png", 1]]];` but still getting same error that the insertObject is nil ... ?!?!?!

Comment: Just tried an image I use in another part of the game that loads before trying to populate the array in question (i.e. the image shows up fine in the game). The image shows up fine in the earlier part of the game but claims to be nil when I try to put it into the array. This seems to indicate the actual array is nil but the way it is initialized looks fine, yes?

Comment: Did you add the sprite sheet to the scene?

Comment: I didn't think I needed one. With the various things I've tried as mentioned in the comments it seems unlikely that would be the issue. Am I completely wrong in that assumption?

Comment: You need to put all your pictures into a sprite sheet ( awesome program for that http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker ) then attach the ".plist" made in the begging of your int. `[ballAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]     
  spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"discoball1200x2008c16-%d.png", i]]];` this code right here is adding the sprite sheet but you dont have one so it makes no sense how it could work

Answer (score 0):

Make a sprite sheet, add it to your int

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"YourAnim.plist"];
```

Now in the animation code

```
[ballAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [YourAnim.png", i]]];
```

When you make a sprite sheet it makes two things, 1) a png with the sprites and 2) a plist with the coordinates

if you so decide to use the program I told you about make sure you set it to cocos2d

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841265/sprite-frame-animation-cocos2d-3-0 this can help you out too

Answer (score 0):

See The code [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349388/cocos2d-sprite-repeat-animation-forever/19373921#19373921)

**Now Change for Cocos2dV3 is below.**

In the link code there is `CCAnimation` that is replace by `CCActionAnimate` in V3 and also `CCRepeatForever` is replace by `CCActionRepeatForever` in V3.

Also check your .plist images may be **10** althougt in for condition it get **11th** image in it. so may be that is your problem to insert image in array,

replace and try.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
{
 // Code
}
```

Change it work fine.